# Bluetooth powers off a couple of seconds after connecting to a device

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth, 20.04

- I have this issue on the same computer running Kubuntu 19 and now 20.
- The issue happens regardless of having installed bluedevil, blueman or gnome-bluetooth (only one of them installed)
- I can scan for devices, connect for instance to my headset but systematically after a couple of seconds I get a bluetooth dev power off. Sometimes it cames back, then off again. What can I do? It seems that similar problems are affecting a lot of people for a long time... any solution/recommendation?
- Thanks in advance.

Please find below the output for /var/log/syslog. At the end the bluetooth manager simply shows the bluetooth disconnected.

```
May  4 19:36:58 laptop NetworkManager[1178]: <info>  [1588617418.3845] manager: (C0:BD:C8:E4:34:D6): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
May  4 19:36:58 laptop NetworkManager[1178]: <info>  [1588617418.3849] device (C0:BD:C8:E4:34:D6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  4 19:36:58 laptop NetworkManager[1178]: <info>  [1588617418.3947] device (C0:BD:C8:E4:34:D6): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May  4 19:37:30 laptop systemd[2468]: Reached target Bluetooth.
May  4 19:37:32 laptop kernel: [35648.423366] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 6
May  4 19:37:32 laptop bluetoothd[1551]: No reply to Open request
May  4 19:37:32 laptop bluetoothd[1551]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
May  4 19:37:32 laptop NetworkManager[1178]: <info>  [1588617452.3624] device (C0:BD:C8:E4:34:D6): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
May  4 19:37:32 laptop bluetoothd[1551]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.206 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May  4 19:37:32 laptop bluetoothd[1551]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.206 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
May  4 19:37:32 laptop systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
May  4 19:37:32 laptop systemd[2468]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
May  4 19:37:32 laptop kernel: [35648.740064] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
May  4 19:37:32 laptop kernel: [35648.893099] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc, bcdDevice= 0.01
May  4 19:37:32 laptop kernel: [35648.893103] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
May  4 19:37:32 laptop kernel: [35648.908496] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 3707100180012d0d2a
May  4 19:37:32 laptop kernel: [35648.908499] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 2a
May  4 19:37:32 laptop bluetoothd[1551]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.206 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May  4 19:37:32 laptop bluetoothd[1551]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.206 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
May  4 19:37:32 laptop NetworkManager[1178]: <info>  [1588617452.9247] manager: (C0:BD:C8:E4:34:D6): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
May  4 19:37:32 laptop NetworkManager[1178]: <info>  [1588617452.9277] device (C0:BD:C8:E4:34:D6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May  4 19:37:32 laptop NetworkManager[1178]: <info>  [1588617452.9326] device (C0:BD:C8:E4:34:D6): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May  4 19:37:33 laptop systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
May  4 19:37:33 laptop systemd[2468]: Reached target Bluetooth.
May  4 19:37:33 laptop NetworkManager[1178]: <info>  [1588617453.9173] device (C0:BD:C8:E4:34:D6): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
May  4 19:39:01 laptop systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
May  4 19:39:01 laptop systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
May  4 19:39:01 laptop systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
```

Comment: You need to prove more information than this. Check `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` for more details.

Comment: added the output of /var/log/syslog in the post above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try disabling the autosuspend feature of the btusb module with

```
echo "options btusb enable_autosuspend=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/btusb.conf
```

Reboot

This should disable any power saving on Bluetooth